What does "cloud scenario" means when using TransactionScope
Following Microsoft documentation with TransactionScope
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions#passing-an-existing-transaction-to-the-context

There are still some limitations to the TransactionScope approach:
Requires .NET 4.5.1 or greater to work with asynchronous methods.
It cannot be used in cloud scenarios unless you are sure you have one
and only one connection (cloud scenarios do not support distributed
transactions).
It cannot be combined with the Database.UseTransaction() approach of
the previous sections.
It will throw exceptions if you issue any DDL and have not enabled
distributed transactions through the MSDTC Service.

I understand "The cloud scenario" as "the runtime environment is not a fully-featured VM"
So

Cloud or local databases do not matters, we can use TransactionScope
If we use full-featured Windows or Linux VMs runtime, we can use TransactionScope
If we use docker images in Kubernetes it may not work?
If we use any cloud-hosting services (Azure AppServices, Elastic BeanStalk...) it will not work ?

Do we have a concrete definition for "cloud scenario"?

Best approach is to do not use TransactionScope in new applications. Without distributed transaction coordinator it is useless.

No, I suspect they mean it won't work with cloud databases/services like AzureDB, Cosmos, etc.  For Azure DB transactions you would need to consider something like elastic transactions. TransactionScope does not wrap/integrate with these.
